# How to represent a state machine with HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, state-machine

On a web page I wish to display an element which depends on the *state* of some JavaScript. *State* like in a state machine. Currently the possible states are these (but I may add more):

- `input`: display some input elements for the user to set. The user can click a button to start some JavaScript processing and move to the `working` state.
- `working`: display a progress bar informing the user that the script is running. The user can cancel the computation (moving back to the `input` state) or the computation can end (moving to either the `result` or `error` state).
- `result`: display the computation result. The user can go back to `input` with a button.
- `error`: display the error. The user can go back to `input` with a button.

The JavaScript part is ready and working, but I'm unsure how to do this in HTML + CSS.

##### Current solution and its issue

Currently I've been doing it with classes: I set a class to a common ancestor element with the same name of the state and I display the right elements based on it. Something like this:

```js
const parent=document.querySelector("#parent");
let timer=null;
function input(){
  parent.classList.remove("working","result","error");
  parent.classList.add("input");
}
function run(){
  parent.classList.remove("input");
  parent.classList.add("working");
  timer=setTimeout(result,1500)
}
function stop(){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  input();
}
function result(){
  parent.classList.remove("working");
  if(Math.random()>0.5){parent.classList.add("result");}
  else{parent.classList.add("error");}
}
input();
```

```css
#input{display:none;}
#working{display:none;}
#result{display:none;}
#error{display:none;}

#parent.input #input{display:block;}
#parent.working #working{display:block;}
#parent.result #result{display:block;}
#parent.error #error{display:block;}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="input">INPUT. <a href="#" onclick="run();">RUN</a></div>
  <div id="working">WORKING. <a href="#" onclick="stop();">STOP</a></div>
  <div id="result">RESULT. <a href="#" onclick="input();">RESTART</a></div>
  <div id="error">ERROR. <a href="#" onclick="input();">RESTART</a></div>
</div>
```

This solution works but it feels *unstable*: in theory it would be possible for the parent element to have no classes (in which case nothing is displayed) or multiple ones (in which case you'd see multiple states at once). This shouldn't happen, but the only thing preventing it is the correctness of my script.

##### Question

Are there better ways to implement this idea of states, so that the HTML elements can't end up in inconsistent states?

Answer (score 0):

Let’s consider the role which HTML plays in a state machine on the web. A machine has moving parts, it is dynamic, so the **core** of any machine on the web must be implemented in Javascript. HTML is useful only to provide the **interface** between the user and the machine. It’s a subtle distinction but it fundamentally changes the way you write it.

Have you ever used React? React provides the framework to create entire web applications as “state machines”. React’s mantra is “UI is a function of state”. In a React app, you have a **single variable** which contains the current state, **rendering code** which builds the UI based on the state, and **core code** (mostly event handlers) which updates the state.

Even if you don’t want to build in React, you can use the same general idea:

- keep the current state in a Javascript variable (typically you’d use an object, but in this case we only need a string)
- write a rendering function which reads the state and then builds the appropriate HTML to represent that state
- in the event handlers for your links, do any operations which are required, update the state and call the rendering function

```js
let state = null
let timer = null

// core code
const input = () => {
  state = 'input'
  render()
}
const run = () => {
  state = 'working'
  render()
  timer = setTimeout(result,1500)
}
const stop = () => {
  clearTimeout(timer)
  state = 'input'
  render()
}
const result = () => {
  if(Math.random()>0.5)
    state = 'result'
  else
    state = 'error'
  render()
}

// rendering code
const render = () => {
  let x = state
  switch(state) {
    case 'input':
      x += ' <a href="#" onclick="run();">run</a>'
      break
    case 'working':
      x += ' <a href="#" onclick="stop();">stop</a>'
      break
    case 'result':
      x += ' <a href="#" onclick="input();">restart</a>'
      break
    case 'error':
      x += ' <a href="#" onclick="input();">restart</a>'
      break
  }
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = x
}

// initialisation code
state = 'input'
render()
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: The asker clearly understands that javascript is required. I'm not sure what your first paragraph is responding "no" to.

Comment: To the title, "How to represent a state machine with HTML elements?" But maybe I will reword it. Thanks.